# Add scenario to context in xbrl instance using jaxb

Tags: jaxb, xbrl

I have generated Java classes for my xbrl taxonomy using xjc. Now I am trying to marshall an xbrl instance. I am able to create scenario tag inside context. But can't find any Java class for adding explicit/typed member. Do I need to add any binding class for the same?
I'm new to jaxb. 
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that the elements you are referring to, *xbrli:scenario* and *xbrldi:typedMember*/*xbrldi:explicitMember*, are in two different schemas: the former is in the [core XBRL schema](https://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd), while the latter are in the [XBRL dimensions-in-instance schema](http://www.xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi-2006.xsd). This is because they came later as an extension to XBRL's segments.

If only the first schema is in scope (e.g., compiled with xjc), the xbrli:segment element can contain anything from other namespaces, as you can see here:

```
<element name="segment">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <any namespace="##other"
           processContents="lax"
           minOccurs="1"
           maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

You need the second schema as well to be aware of the other two tags or create them.

Having said that, I am am not familiar with JAXB enough to tell if it supports this ##other construct natively, but I hope it helps you further. I would think that if the xbrldi schema is in the DTS, then there should be Java classes corresponding to it.